# Predicate Logic: Deduction for Quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

So, I was bothered by the question of natural deduction wherein we have to prove ∀h(Fh ⇒ Fk) from premise ∃g Fg ⇒ Fk given that k is a constant which isn't used before

To get the conclusion in ∀(_) form, we should deduce Fk from Fh. Using existential quantifier premise, we might obtain Fk for variable g but in conclusion the variable altogether is changed (g to h). So, how do we go about proving the conclusion from given premises with the aid of formal proof rules we have like Introduction and Elimination rules?

Comment: Do you know the rules for quantifiers?

Comment: If so, assume $Fh$ and derive $Fk$ form the premise.

Comment: Yeah but how do we separate terms Fg and Fk from the existential quantifier premise?

Comment: Look to the Existential Introduction rule.

Comment: New hint: assume $Fh$ (see above): how can we move from $Fh$ to $\exists g Fg$? Answer: review list of ND rules.

Comment: I applied Existential Elimination to get Fa ⇒ Fk. 
Now I need to prove Fk from Fh. So, would it be right if I use the fact that a exists to get Fa from Fh and then use Modus Ponens in Fa ⇒ Fk to derive Fk?

Comment: If so, what is the rule I need to use from the given Fh and a exists to derive Fk?